# Replace a substring that occurs after a given offset

Tags: javascript, replace, substring

I have a string that has following format:

```
'User ID: 2894, Task ID: 68, Some other text'
```

Let's say I need to convert this string to the following:

```
'User ID: 2684, Task ID: <replaced>, Some other text'
```

Obviously, the way to do this is to replace string `68` with the string `<replaced>`.

```js
var str = 'User ID: 2894, Task ID: 68, Some other text';
var newStr = str.replace('68', '<replaced>');
alert(newStr);
```

But this could blow up on my face if `User ID` contained the same sequence of numerals.

```js
var str = 'User ID: 2684, Task ID: 68, Some other text';
var newStr = str.replace('68', '<replaced>');
alert(newStr);
```

However, I also have information about the character index of the substring that should be replaced. So I have following code to do this task:

```js
var str = 'User ID: 2684, Task ID: 68, Some other text';
var taskId = '68';
var prefix = 'Task ID: ';
var index = str.indexOf(prefix) + prefix.length;
var newStr = str.substring(0, index) + '<replaced>' + str.substring(index + taskId.length);
alert(newStr);
```

As you can see, now I need to call `substring` twice to get the result. But is there a simpler code which I could use to replace a substring that occurs after a given offset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add your prefix to the replace function.

```
var str = 'User ID: 2894, Task ID: 68, Some other text';
var prefix = 'Task ID: ';
var newStr = str.replace(prefix + '68' + ',', prefix + '<replaced>,');
alert(newStr);
```

// EDIT* Adding a comma suffix here too, in case there is some other Task ID number starting with 68. Obviously this answer assumes it won't always be a 68 that you're replacing, and whatever number will be passed into this function.

Comment: Although this will work for your example, you'll run into problems with a string like this:
`'User ID: 2894, Task ID: 6845, Some other text'`
A better way to do this would be to split your comma separated string, split all of those by the colon (assuming they are all key-value pairs, but in your example they are not.) and make sure the value is exactly '68'. I'll write a different answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: That seems over-complicated, and you'd run into issues if there's a comma contained in any string. Your point is valid though, if that's a use-case. An adjustment to this answer would be to add a comma suffix too. `'Task ID: ' + '68' + ','`

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer. Less error prone. It would certainly be easier to work with this string if it were JSON.

```
var targetId = '68';

var str = 'User ID: 2894, Task ID: 68, Some other text';
var items = str.split(', ');
var prefix = 'Task ID: ';

var foundIndex = items.indexOf(prefix + targetId);
if(foundIndex > -1){
    items.splice(foundIndex, 1, prefix + '<replaced>');
}
var newStr = items.join(', ');
alert(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you count on the delimiters and the location of the text you want to replace in relation to the delimiters? If so, here's couple methods of replacing text `split`ing and `splice`ing on delimiters.

Simpler one, `split` on comma, replace second element in its entirety:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/2jLbmop5/)

```
var str = 'User ID: 2894, Task ID: 68, Some other text'
arr1 = str.split(', ')
arr1.splice(1, 1, 'Task ID: <replaced>')
str = arr1.join(', ')
console.log(str)
```

A little more complex, first `split` on comma, then colon:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/gLs5dznn/)

```
var str = 'User ID: 2894, Task ID: 68, Some other text'
arr1 = str.split(', ')
arr2 = arr1[1].split(': ')
arr2.splice(1, 1, '<replaced>')
arr1[1] = arr2.join(': ')
str = arr1.join(', ')
console.log(str)
```

Simply an alternative to `replace`. I think the `replace` option is better for the case you presented.